# Fazer botão 'submit' esperar ação de um alert?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um formulário HTML com um botão submit. Valido os campos no click do botão,caso estes estejam inválidos, é exibido um alerta, mas este desaparece rapidamente e o formulário já redireciona pra página do action. Só funciona quando mudo o tipo do botão para button.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Poste o código do seu form pra gente analisar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem ver seu código fica um pouco complicado de responder com certeza, mas acredito que seja porque o comportamento padrão do *submit* está sendo disparado.

Você pode usar [**`Event.preventDefault`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/event/preventDefault) para prevenir a ação *default*. Após fazer a validação, se estiver tudo correto você pode usar [**`HTMLFormElement.submit()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) para enviar o formulário.

```
var input = document.querySelector('input'),
    form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', validateAndSubmit, false);

function validateAndSubmit(event) {
  // Prevenindo o comportamento padrão.
  event.preventDefault();

  // Pegando o valor do input.
  var value = input.value;

  // Fazendo a validação e enviando caso esteja OK.
  if (value.length < 5)
    alert('O formulário não será enviado, a palavra não possui 5 caracteres.');

  else {
    alert('O formulário será enviado.');
    form.submit();
  }
}
```

Não é possível simular o envio do formulário nos snippets do StackOverflow, então coloquei o script [**nesse fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fu7c2dug/).

Comment: Muito obrigada! Exatamente o que eu queria.

Answer (score 2):

O ideal é chamar a função de validação no `onSubmit` do formulário, e caso der algo errado na validação, retornar `false`, assim o formulário não é enviado.

```js
function valida() {

  if( ! document.getElementById('nome').value ) {

    alert('Preencha o campo "Nome"');
    return false;
  
  } else {
  
    return true;
    
  }

}
```

```html
<form action="" method="get" onsubmit="return valida();">
  <input id="nome" type="text"/>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```